# How do I change part of an XML attribute in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am doing a lot of XML parsing/transformation using the org.w3c.dom classes.

I have two attributes: "length" and "validation".

I have parsed the XML document, have the two attributes in Node objects (e.g. Node nodeLengthAttr = attr.getNamedItem("length");)

I want to search through the "validation" attribute and input the value of length at a specific point using .setTextContext or a similar method. So vailidation would then be "Some text +length+ some test".

I basically want to treat the attribute like a string, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a

```
import org.w3c.dom;
//...
Attr attrValidation = (Attr)attr.getNamedItem("validation");
String value = attrValidation.getValue();
//Modify the string
//...
attrValidation.setValue(value);
```

is what you are looking for. Hard to say without a bit more context.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure, your `Node` instance is an element, cast it to `org.w3c.dom-Element`.

- Then use `Element.getAttribute()` to get the attribute value as a `String`.
- Create your modified string.
- Set the modified string with `Element.setAttribute()`.

Example:

```
if(node instanceof Element) {
  Element el = (Element) node;
  String s = el.getAttribute("validation");
  String modified = ...
  el.setAttribute("validation", modified);
}
```